# iOS 8 Video Editing App That Lets You Hear The Audio While Trimming?

Tags: editing, iphone, ios

I'm interested in making perfectly-looping Vine videos of me playing guitar riffs. I'd like to shoot and edit these videos on my phone (iPhone 5, iOS 8.1), without using a desktop editor. **Is there an app that allows you to hear audio while editing?....**

Now that you can import videos created elsewhere into Vine, I thought this would be a pretty straightforward thing. However, in order to create a video of this type that loops the way I want it to, I'll need to be able to hear the audio while trimming the clip in order to set the start/end points correctly…and **every video editing app I've found silences the audio when you're in editing mode.** Right? Am I crazy?

I've tried:

- iMovie
- Splice
- uh...a few others I can't remember right now

If anyone knows of a video app that lets you hear audio while you're editing and could tell me about it, I'd be eternally grateful. I feel like I must be missing something here…

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that a smartphone is still a pretty low power device for doing any kind of video editing.  They don't have a lot of resources available, any editing software available is extremely limited and really, unless you have some pressing need to do it, you will have a far easier and better quality time doing it on a desktop.  I'm not sure that any phone based tool is far enough along to support what you are looking for as it sounds like you've looked at most of the few attempts.

Comment: Thanks, AJ. This is a pretty basic editing task, though, and the phone is plenty capable in terms of raw power and UI (though, as you point out, perhaps no one has yet created an app that can do it). Anyone else have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind phones aren't as powerful as they may at first seem.  Yes, modern smart phones have processing speeds measured in Ghz, just like desktops and they have multiple cores, however they are not the same kinds of cores.  ARM chips are designed for low power operation and have a reduced set of instructions compared to an x86 chip in your PC.  Many of the functions that are cut out are functions that were introduced on PCs to help with things like processing video and images.  This means that when it comes to advanced operations, phones aren't nearly as powerful as you might think.

Answer (score 1):

There're many great video editing apps in the AppStore. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to name a specific app according to the StackExchange policy (my previous answer was banned). Some of them play sound while you do video editing (trimming, applying video effects, etc.)

For sure smartphones now have enough computational power to do very complex video editing, they have GPU for even better performance. As a such kind of apps developer I admit that only a tiny fraction of professional desktop video editing software features couldn't be implemented on a smartphone. The major limitation is the screen size. It is freaking hard to make an intuitive user interface and a great user experience on such a small screen.

Comment: Note that if you are going to be active on the site and answering other questions as well, it is fine to mention your own application by name (and even link to it).  You just have to clearly indicate that you are one one of the developers of it and not have the majority of your answers be promoting your app.